# Exchange the authorization code for an access token in google sign in

Tags: python, google-api, google-signin, google-oauth

I am following this tutorial to implement google sign in in my python server application but [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_7_exchange_the_authorization_code_for_an_access_token), they used libraries that aren't built in python and I can't find them.

```
from apiclient import discovery
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
```

How to install them ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing them using `pip` in the command line.

```
pip install apiclient httplib2 oauth2client
```

Comment: oauth2client is deprecated for google-oauth, how can I do the same thing with it ?